# Enable/Disable Record Specific Controls in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to enable/disable some checkboxes based on another fields value for a specific record in a datasheet form.

If I use vba, it seems that the every record is disable/enabled (using the following code) no matter which event i place it under.

```
If Me.x = "N/A" Then
    Me.y.Enabled = False
Else
    Me.y.Enabled = True
End If
```

Furthermore, since its a checkbox control, i cant use conditional formatting like i do for textboxes and etc....

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can't. All controls in the detail section of a continuous form or datasheet form share **one** set of properties. If you disable a control, you disable all instances of it.

What you can do is place code in the OnDirty event of the checkbox:

```
Private Sub y_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.x = "N/A" Then
        Msgbox "Sorry pal!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

It's not quite as intuitive, of course.

Comment: conditional formatting for textboxes somehow could.. so i thought i could exploit that logic and apply to checkboxes somehow.. but ill try this code. thank!

Comment: Yes, for textboxes this would work with conditional formatting. But not checkboxes. You could try to add visual feedback with an unbound textbox behind the checkbox, that gets a red background for x = "N/A", but it would probably look silly.

Comment: unbound textbox, is that method applicable to datasheet view forms?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about the datasheet view. No, it isn't, I think (I rarely use it).